# Android Handlers and Asynctask

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks, android-asynctask, handler

I am half way through my android application for my assignment. Now, I am kind of confused. My problem is:
I have a Main Class ( a fragment in this case) and what is does( among other things) is that it gets the url of an image given the persons name and then it downloads the image from that url. Here is how I have planed to proceed:

I have the two asynctask in separate class because I will need them for other classes too in the future. I am not sure about what I have done and I dont want any memory leaks so the app wont crash. I would really aprreciate if someone could take a look and suggest me otherwise.

```
Main Class() {
static MyHandler myhandler;
...
... 
....

static class MyHandler extends Handler {
....
.....
.......
  public void HandleMessage()
 {
 .....
 .......
  if(message == "OK")
    {
     download();
    }
  else if(message = "BMP")
    {
      // I am done
     ....
     ......
    } 
  }
 }


 image_url_fetch(myhandler).execute;

 public void download()
 {
  image_download(myhandler).execute;
 }

 }


 class image_url_fetch exteds Asynctask 
{

 MyHandler myhandler;

 image_url_fetch(MyHandler myhandler)
 {
  this.myhandler = myhandler;
 }
  ...
  ....
  onPostExecute()
 {
myhandler.sendmessage("OK");
 }

}  

class image_download extends Asynctask  
{

 MyHandler myhandler;

 image_download(MyHandler myhandler)
 {
  this.myhandler = myhandler;
 }
  ...
  ....
  onPostExecute() 
 {
  handler.sendMessage(BMP)
    // i have to find a way to send the Bitmap to Main Class
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

its better to use both fetching Image Url and Downloading Image in same AsyncTask instead two

Code looks Like bit Simplified and faster.

In case you no need AsyncTask for fetching Url ...because it wont take ample time to retrieve a series of characters. Use the logic to fetch Url in image_download AsyncTask before downloading image .

**P.S :** For Better Readability and Standards Use Class Names starting with Capital Letter and Avoid Using Special Symbols in Class Names..example

ImageDownloader.java Would be Awesome to Read and Understand Context without describing

Comment: Thank you. But I have instances where I need to use the two classes separately. So I am keeping them independent. Can you point out where the memory leaks might happen? Say the main class was destroyed, what are the chances of memory leaks here. I am not good at figuring that out.

Comment: its Not about memory Leaks ..its about Memory Optimization,instances Increase the memory Utilization .... and if you need to get url of image separately ,better wrap the logic in method without Asyncask and call that method in download AsyncTask

Comment: Ok thank you. In case my MainClass got destroyed, then do the other classes that might have been already instantiated and working on the background get GC ( I think the outer classes dont have reference to the MainClass (i might be wrong)?

Comment: instances have scope upto block.As you  destroy your MainClass,the instances in the scope of class gets Destroyed ,in your Language GC releases their Memories too